# Why does'nt Context class has no startActivityWIthResult method?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application, which is including a library which exposes set of methods via a public class. Internally, this library uses the context passed on to it by the application.

**Question**: Since the public class in the library does not extend Activity, the methods use the Context object passed on to it by the application. In this case how to communicate the result/data back to the application? The context object does not have startActivityWithResult() method.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is no any method like `startActivityWithResult()` for Activity, the method is `startActivityForResult()`.

If your **context is Activity** reference then you can use `startActivityForResult()` method in that class. just use like,

`((Activity)context).startActivityForResult();`

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am getting a java.lang.classcastexception: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity, anything I am missing here?

Comment: Yes, As I mentioned in my answer, your context should be reference of Activity class, not a Application class.